# What is the difference between len(x) and len(x)-1?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range

I'm sorry for the very basic question, this is a concept I can't quite grasp.

It is my understanding that the first element in a Python list has index `[0]`. This means that `len(x)-1` should be the last element in my list x.
So, if I write a loop with:

```py
for i in range(0, len(x)-1):
  #do stuff here
```

This should mean that I want I to go from the first element of my list to the last one.
However, I always find written:

```py
for i in range(0, len(x)):
  #do stuff here
```

Why is that?
Which one is correct?

Comment: `for i in range(len(x)):` is "unpythonic", you should use `for obj in x:`. If you need the index you should use `for i, obj in enumerate(x):`

Comment: Check the documentation if you do not know how something works: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range):   `class range(start, stop[, step])`  _For a positive `step`, the contents of a range `r` are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and **`r[i] < stop`**._ So any element is strictly smaller then stop ..

Answer (score 0):

`range(0,x)` will loop up to the value of `x`, so `< x` as opposed to `<= x`. For example, `range(0, 3)` will loop over the indices `0, 1, 2`.

Which means the second one is correct, as if `x = [4, 5, 6, 7]` (len 4) - the maximum index is 3 so you'd want to loop over the indices `0, 1, 2, 3`.

Answer (score 0):

`range(x, y)` means to start with `x` and iterate till `y-1` so when you use `for i in range(0, len(x)-1):`, it will iterate from `0` to `len(x) - 2`.

For example if, `len(x) = 3`, the statement `for i in range(0, len(x)-1):` will iterate from `0` to `1` so that's why we use `for i in range(0, len(x)):` to iterate over all the elements in the list.